# Python: Reading multiple CSV files, and assigning each to a different variable

Tags: python, loops, csv

I would like to read all the CSV files in my path and assign them each to a different variable name within my python code. 
For example,

```
dshfd9438dks.csv
ansjewi38Ekd.csv
```

Would turn into:

```
df1 and df2
```

The code I have now is:

```
for f in glob.iglob('*.csv'): 
df = pd.read_csv(f, low_memory=False)
```

How would I manipulate it to add a number to the df var?

Comment: dictionary as stated is the way. Variables are meant to be a developers reflection with no automation in creation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Use a dictionary for a variable number of variables

It's poor practice to name linked variables explicitly. In this case, you can use a dictionary with `enumerate`:

```
dfs = {}
for idx, f in enumerate(glob.iglob('*.csv'), 1):
    dfs[idx] = pd.read_csv(f, low_memory=False)
```

If you wish, you can convert this into a dictionary comprehension:

```
files = enumerate(glob.iglob('*.csv'), 1)
dfs = {idx: pd.read_csv(f, low_memory=False) for idx, f in files}
```

Then access your dataframes via `dfs[1]`, `dfs[2]`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Why not put them in a dictionary?

```
dfs = dict(("df{}".format(i), pd.read_csv(f)) for i,f in enumerate(glob.iglob('*.csv')))
```